# I have a Cargo run error, on rocket_cors method

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I'm trying to get my rust rocket app working through cargo run

```
use rocket::http::Method;

fn make_cors() -> Cors {
  let allowed_origins = AllowedOrigins::some_exact(&[ // 4.
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://0.0.0.0:8000",
  ]);
  CorsOptions { // 5.
    allowed_origins,
    allowed_methods: vec![Method::Get].into_iter().map(From::from).collect(), // 1.
    allowed_headers: AllowedHeaders::some(&[
      "Authorization",
      "Accept",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", // 6.
    ]),
    allow_credentials: true,
    ..Default::default()
  }.to_cors().expect("error while building CORS")
}
```

The following error is bugging me:

```
the trait bound `rocket_cors::Method: std::convert::From<rocket::http::Method>` is not satisfied
the trait `std::convert::From<rocket::http::Method>` is not implemented for `rocket_cors::Method`
```

Edit:

fixed to rocket_cors::Method

which is now giving me the following error:

```
  no associated item named `Get` found for struct `rocket_cors::Method` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:24:35
   |
24 |     allowed_methods: vec![Method::Get].into_iter().map(From::from).collect(), // 1.
   |                                   ^^^ associated item not found in `rocket_cors::Method`
```

Comment: Please always include the **full** error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`Method` wrapped by the `rocket_cors`](https://docs.rs/rocket_cors/latest/rocket_cors/struct.Method.html), not the one from `rocket` itself, since according to what `rocket_cors` has said

> A wrapper type around `rocket::http::Method` to support serialization and deserialization.

so they're not the same.

Comment: edited above take a look

Comment: please, read the doc (both TRPL & and crate doc), as the wrapper `rocket_cors::http::Method` is not an enum but a struct, and it implements [`From<rocket::http::Method>`](https://docs.rs/rocket_cors/latest/rocket_cors/struct.Method.html#impl-From%3CMethod%3E)

Comment: I needed to update rocket_cors to 0.5.2

Answer (score 0):

The Rocket CORS library requires this form of implementation:

```
use rocket_cors::{AllowedHeaders, AllowedMethods, AllowedOrigins, Cors, CorsOptions};
use std::str::FromStr;

pub fn fairing() -> Cors {
    let allowed_origins = AllowedOrigins::All;
    let allowed_methods: AllowedMethods = ["Get", "Post", "Delete"]
        .iter()
        .map(|s| FromStr::from_str(s).unwrap())
        .collect();

    CorsOptions {
        allowed_origins,
        allowed_methods,
        allowed_headers: AllowedHeaders::All,
        allow_credentials: true,
        ..Default::default()
    }
    .to_cors()
    .expect("error while building CORS")
}
```

You can check it out [here](https://github.com/lawliet89/rocket_cors/blob/985098dd8f3b052716111eaa872d184cc21a1a68/src/lib.rs#L869)